# Unable to connect to running ssh-agent

Tags: server, ssh-agent, sockets

I connect to a long-running screen session on Ubuntu 12.04 server, and use that as a jump box for other things I connect to. As a result, I want a long-running ssh-agent on that machine. To that end, I have the following in my .bashrc:

```
pgrep -u pdickey ssh-agent > /dev/null || ssh-agent -a $HOME/.ssh-auth-sock
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$HOME/.ssh-auth-sock
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK
```

As long as my screen session never disconnects, this works perfectly. I can spawn new screens, and they all get the same agent. Trouble arises when I disconnect from the machine that has the original ssh session. On a reconnect, I get the following:

```
$ ssh-add -l
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
```

Everything I've found about this seems to indicate that this happens when the agent isn't running, but I can verify that it is running, and the $SSH_AUTH_SOCK variable is set:

```
$ ps -fu pdickey | grep ssh-agent
pdickey    435     1  0 04:11 ?        00:00:00 ssh-agent -a /home/pdickey/.ssh-auth-sock
$ echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
/home/pdickey/.ssh-auth-sock
```

So why the heck isn't it connecting? I own the socket:

```
$ ls -la .ssh-auth-sock 
srw------- 1 pdickey pdickey 0 Mar 10 04:33 .ssh-auth-sock=
```

I've even gone so far as to strace the process, which after sifting through all the library loads, provides the mostly-unhelpful bit of information:

```
64962 connect(3, {sa_family=AF_FILE, path="/home/pdickey/.ssh-auth-sock"}, 110) = -1 ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
```

This is now the limit of my linux / ubuntu / ssh knowledge. Why would a socket that I own, created by a process I own, refuse connection from another process I own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So turns out this is a result of deciding to encrypt my home directories, and placing the auth-sock there... This means when I fully detach from screen, my running programs lose access to my home directory, which breaks ssh-agent. It doesn't kill the ssh-agent process like deleting the socket normally does, and it doesn't remove the socket because it's in an encrypted directory that the machine can no longer access. This also manifests other oddities like my cron daemon not being able to run scripts in my home directory if I'm not logged in.